# Fast Related records access section

Tags: visualforce

I have replaced standard account layout with a visual force page.

Tags:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="true">
    <chatter:feedWithFollowers entityId="{!account.Id}" />
    <apex:detail subject="{!account.id}" relatedList="false" title="false" showchatter="false"/> 
</apex:page>
```

Result:
[image: Result]

I´ve lost section to fast access records related to account (yellow in the pic):
[image]

Do you know how can i show again it in a visual force page?

Thanks in adavantage for any advice.

Comment: Try to set `relatedList="true"`. The access section shows exactly a number or records in every related list. No related lists - no access section.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But i´m adding related lists with  <apex:relatedList .For this i ve relatedList="false". I don t want to show related list of the standard layout. Do you have another idea?

Comment: No chance without related lists.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following links:

http://salesforceworld.blogspot.in/2011/08/displaying-pop-up-summaries-on-hover-in.html

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000950YIAQ

Answer (score 0):

You could just put an anchor just above your apex:detail tags:

```
<a id="myAnchor"></a>
```

Then you'd have to build a simple nav. at the top of the page pointing to your anchors:

```
<a href="#myAnchor"></a>
```